# Is kranz anatomy not a defining feature of $C_4$ plant?

Tags: botany, homework, photosynthesis, plant-anatomy

In **NCERT Class 11** [chapter 13](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kebo113.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjR2-yTqeSBAxUPSWwGHRY5DtEQFnoECDsQAQ&usg=AOvVaw2QXTx1MFMr45dMkXqXgknu) it is written that

> The particularly large cells around the vascular bundles of the C4 plants are called bundle sheath cells, and the leaves which have such anatomy are said to have ‘Kranz’ anatomy.

In [Chapter 6](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&opi=89978449&url=https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/kebo106.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiu1PvTqeSBAxWzcmwGHUfFBmoQFnoECA4QBg&usg=AOvVaw0XfnGkNnhWq5CFdwig0Ex5) it is written for dicot leaf that

> The vascular bundles are surrounded by a layer of thick walled bundle sheath cells.

So we can infer that every dicot is $C_4$ plant but when I searched on Google I found that it is not.

Where am I missing? Is the kranz anatomy not a defining feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your conclusion doesn't follow logically.

Statement 1: C4 plants have photosynthetic bundle sheath cells arranged in a Kranz anatomy. *(I was actually not able to find your quote in the linked chapter, maybe my mistake.)*

Statement 2: Dicots have bundle sheath cells.

It does not follow that Kranz anatomy isn't a characteristic of C4, because the presence or absence of bundle sheath is not the same as Kranz anatomy.

Looking at [a different educational site](https://byjus.com/biology/kranz-anatomy/) (I have no opinion about this site, but it seems fine):

> Kranz anatomy is a specialized structure in C4 Plants where the mesophyll cells are clustered around the bundle-sheath cells in a ring-like fashion. The number of chloroplasts in the bundle-sheath cells is more than that in the mesophyll cells. This is found in C4 grasses such as maize and a few dicots.

**So Kranz anatomy is not presence of bundle sheath, but rather a specific arrangement of the bundle sheath with regard to the mesophyll.**

Note that C3 and C4 aren't nearly as binary or distinct as we might pretend they are- [C4 has in fact arisen multiple times from C3 in evolution](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj9ks6KzOmBAxXwCjQIHVMrCXAQFnoECA4QAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov%2Fpmc%2Farticles%2FPMC4242257%2F&usg=AOvVaw19oYMCVQ2ob8N52ZXCphW8&opi=89978449), so C3/4 are not even taxonomically groups, but rather grouped based on a characteristic metabolism. A few C3 species therefore seem to share some of the anatomical arrangements.

However, the anatomical arrangement is obligate for C4 plants, whereas it is a rarity in C3. See the beginning of [this paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21636408/):

> Kranz anatomy and C(4) vein pattern are required for C(4) biochemical functioning in C(4) plants...

In conclusion:

1. Don't trust your textbook completely. Seek out other sources of information. Wikipedia is quite good for this, these days.
2. C4 and C3 are distinguished by relatively subtle features, some of which are convoluted with the features of e.g. grasses, which can be either C3 or C4.
3. I found your textbook somewhat confusingly written. However, note that at no point did it make strong statements of classification about C3/4 (that I could find). Instead, it simply aimed to describe some anatomical examples. Know when you're doing description, and when you're doing classification! Ideally the book would have a direct comparison of features laid out very clearly, maybe like [this](https://biologydictionary.net/c3-c4-cam-plants/), for the task of doing classification.